# How to pass "ask for text" input to "Run Shell Script"

Tags: shell, automator

My Automator has two boxes:

1) Ask for Text
2) Shell Script

I don't know how to pass the contents of (1) to (2).
The workflow aims to take in files and rename them using the text entered.
So:

```
for f in "$@"
do
    text_entered=????
path/to/my/command "$f" "text_entered"
done
```

That is as much as I can do with my zero knowledge in programming :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to pass user inputs to the shell scripts:

a) Through read command
b) Through command-line arguments

For example:

```
read text_entered #will seek user input for entering the text
```

or

`sh script.sh <text>` 
Here `<text>` refers to the first argument given to the script which may be the text input passed to the script for usage during execution (as variable $1 in the script).

inside the script.sh file, pass $1 to text_entered variable

example:

```
text_entered=$1
```

If the order of text to be entered matches with the argument list in $@ then you may also put the text in a prenamed file (say texts.txt) and read the same during the course of for loop as follows:

```
counter=1
for f in "$@"
do
    text_entered=`sed $counter'!d' texts.txt`
    path/to/my/command $f text_entered
    counter=`expr $counter + 1`
done
```

Comment: Thanks. If text_entered is $1, what is the inputs from "workflow received files/folders". I had understood that it is $1 the first "input", and $2 the second (text), in the order passed. Also, if it's a loop and I use $1 $2, I can't use $@, so I am stuck with just passing one variable.

Comment: You need to specify your problem statement better, but I have tried to understand your question and added another scenario of possibility. See if that helps